# Find the Laurent series of the following function in the given domain as follows.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, laurent-series

Find the series of the following function in the given domain.

1. $f(z) = \frac{z^2+2z-4}{(z^2-9)(z+1)}, 1 < |z| < 3$.
2. $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2+1}, 0 < |z+i| < 2$.

**Attempt:**

1. Notice that
   \begin{equation*}
   \frac{z^2+2z-4}{(z^2-9)(z+1)} = \frac{5}{8} \cdot \frac{1}{z+1} - \frac{1}{12} \cdot \frac{1}{z+3} + \frac{11}{24} \cdot \frac{1}{z-3}.
   \end{equation*}
   For $1 < |z|$, we have $\frac{1}{|z|} < 1$. For $|z| < 3$, we have $\left|\frac{z}{3} \right| < 1$. Hence, for $1 < |z| < 3$, we have
   \begin{align*}
   f(z) &= \frac{5}{8} \cdot \frac{1}{z+1} - \frac{1}{12} \cdot \frac{1}{z+3} + \frac{11}{24} \cdot \frac{1}{z-3} \\
   &= \frac{5}{8} \cdot \frac{1}{z} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + (\frac{1}{z})} - \frac{1}{12} \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{(\frac{z}{3}) + 1} - \frac{11}{24} \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - (\frac{z}{3})} \\
   &= \frac{5}{8} \cdot \frac{1}{z} \cdot \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{n+1} - \frac{1}{36} \cdot \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-\frac{z}{3} \right)^n - \frac{11}{72} \cdot \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{z}{3} \right)^n.
   \end{align*}
2. Notice that
   \begin{equation*}
   \frac{1}{z^2+1} = \frac{i}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{z+i} - \frac{i}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{z-i}.
   \end{equation*}
   For $|z+i| < 2$, we have $\left|\frac{z+i}{2} \right| < 1$, so that
   \begin{align*}
   f(z) &= \frac{i}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{z+i} - \frac{i}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{z-i} \\
   &= \frac{i}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{z+i} - \frac{i}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{(z+i) - 2i} \\
   &= \frac{i}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{z+i} + \frac{i}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2i} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - (\frac{z+i}{2i})} \\
   &= \frac{i}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{z+i} + \frac{1}{4} \cdot \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{z+i}{2i} \right)^n,
   \end{align*}
   which is valid for $0 < |z+i| < 2$.

$ $

$ $

Am I correct? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Does it say about which point you must find the series?

Comment: @JackT No, it does not.

Comment: @JackT What do you mean about "point" ? The question is to find the Laurent series of those given function.

Comment: Yes, a Laurent series of a function is defined about a given point - just read the first paragraph of the wiki article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series .

Comment: @JackT For 1, $c=0$, and for 2, $c=-i$. Does it answered your question?

Comment: How about my attempt above? Is it clear?